# Write a mysql not in query as join

Tags: mysql

I have two tables vtiger_crmentity and vtiger_crmentityrel (from open source project vtiger).

**vtiger_crmentity**

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| crmid        | int(19)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| smcreatorid  | int(19)      | NO   | MUL | 0       |       |
| smownerid    | int(19)      | NO   | MUL | 0       |       |
| modifiedby   | int(19)      | NO   | MUL | 0       |       |
| setype       | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| description  | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| createdtime  | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| modifiedtime | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| viewedtime   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| status       | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| version      | int(19)      | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| presence     | int(1)       | YES  |     | 1       |       |
| deleted      | int(1)       | NO   | MUL | 0       |       |
| label        | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

**vtiger_crmentityrel**

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| crmid     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| module    | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| relcrmid  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| relmodule | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I am trying to get a list of contacts which are not present in the crmentityrel table (in the relcrmid column to be specific). I can do this via a subquery but it is taking about 2 minutes to complete (for about 20k records in each table).

I tried to convert the query to a join but i am surely doing something wrong as i keep getting wrong values (compared to the subquery which i know is right).

Any help is greatly appreciated. Please tell me if you need any details from my side

Edit - 
My working query (with subquery) is -

```
SELECT crmid, label from vtiger_crmentity 
WHERE deleted = 0 and setype="Contacts" 
 and crmid not in (select relcrmid from vtiger_crmentityrel 
where relmodule="Contacts")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert a `not in` to a `join`, the idea is to use `left join` and `where`:

```
SELECT c.crmid, c.label
FROM vtiger_crmentity  c left join
     vtiger_crmentityrel cr
     on c.crmid = cr.relcrmid and relmodule = 'Contacts'
WHERE c.deleted = 0 and c.setype = 'Contacts' and cr.relcrmid is null;
```

I should point out that the above is not *exactly* equivalent.  `NOT IN` returns no rows if the subquery returns even a single `NULL` value.  The above behaves more intuitively.

Because of the behavior of `NOT IN` with `NULL` values, `NOT EXISTS` is a better choice.  Plus, it often has better performance as well:

```
SELECT crmid, label 
FROM vtiger_crmentity c
WHERE deleted = 0 and setype = 'Contacts' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT relcrmid 
                  FROM vtiger_crmentityrel  cr
                  WHERE cr.relmodule = 'Contacts' and cr.relcrmid = c.crmid
                 );
```